# How do you get a parse user profile picture in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

i want to get a list of users profile pictures in my uitable view, how do i do this, this is what i have so far

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
PFUser *user = (PFUser *)[self.users objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){

PFFile *theImage = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
NSData *imageData = [theImage getData];
UIImage *profileImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

NSLog(@"%@",profileImage);

if (profileImage == nil) {
} else {
    cell.imageView.image = profileImage;
}

}];
```

The code below runs but the output says null.

I do this same thing for getting the profile picture for the current user and it get the profile picture, but it wouldn't return the image for other users.

note that `self.user` already contains pfusers

here is where i get all users searched for:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:self.myTextField.text];
        self.users = [query findObjects];
        NSLog(@"Thing is: %@",self.users);
        [self.mytableView reloadData];
    }];

    return YES;
}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Your second code block looks way out of whack...you are finding the objects twice, which shouldn't be the case. Try this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:self.myTextField.text];
    self.users = [query findObjects];
    NSLog(@"Thing is: %@",self.users);
    [self.mytableView reloadData];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: yea im aware of that sorry for including that but cheers, it still returns null !